# How to recover corrupted database data due to character set

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I am taking up a rails application that has a MySQL database. It is a web application that has an international audience. After few days of work, I noticed that all the tables and the database itself has latin1_sweedish_ci as collation. Later, in text fields, I discovered mumble jumble like this:

```
It&acirc;Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã¢â€žÂ¢s educational and
```

Obviously it is due to the wrong character set. If it were UTF-8, this would have not happen. But as this has happened, can we recover/transform this corrupted data to utf?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to mysqldump the DB, pass the dump through iconv, then reload.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this... first take back up of your database... Then make one script which will fetch records one by one and perfom utf8_decode and then store it again in database... but before that change charchter set to utf8...

Answer (score -1):

You could also try to convert all the columns to binary and then to UTF-8. See [mysqlperformanceblog.com](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/12/18/fixing-column-encoding-mess-in-mysql/comment-page-1/#comment-220118) and [dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-conversion.html) for more information.